# How to dynamicaly construct a type from multiple properties?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I am studying on advanced types in Typescript, what I have so far is a `type x` that takes a generic argument `props extends string`. Given as value for `props` is `name | age | email` this constructs the following type:

```
{
  name: "name",
  age: "age",
  email: "email"    
}
```

The above type is generated by the following type definition:

```
type x<Property extends string> = { [K in Property]: K }
```

Also I have a type constructor for the above type:

```
let x = <props extends string>(p: props): x<props> => (<x<props>>{[p]: p})
```

I can produce a type by simply passing a property, of type string, to function `x`:

```
x("name") // Type is x<"name">
```

What I would like to do is pass multiple properties to `x`, in such a way that: 
`x("name", "age", "email")` produces type `x<"name" | "age" | "email">`.

I know that I can achieve that by refactoring the method `x` like this:

```
let x = <props extends string>(...p: props[]): x<props> => null! // Don't know how to implement this
```

But I don't know how construct a concrete object from that input, simular to `(<x<props>>{[p]: p})`, but iterate over all the properties passed to `x`.

So is there a way to iterate over the properties and dynamicly construct a type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to iterate over the props and assign them to a new object:

```
type x<Property extends string> = { [K in Property]: K }


let x = <props extends string>(...p: props[]): x<props> => {
    let result = {} as x<props>
    for (let k of p) {
        result[k] = k
    }
    return result;
} 

let a = x("name", "age") // Type is x<"name">
console.log(a);
```

There is no magic syntax to produce this object in a single expression, so we use a type assertion to lie to the compiler that `{}` is `x<props>` and fix up the object in the `for` after. Sometimes type assertions are necessary, this is one of those times, since we have special information that the compiler does not have (the information that we will make `{}` into a valid `x<props>` in the next couple of lines)

Or a more succint one line version:

```
let x = <props extends string>(...p: props[]): x<props> => p.reduce((o, k) => (o[k] = k, o), {} as x<props>);
```

Comment: Then I might also just use `props.foreach(prop => ...)`, it is that this is a school project for a software engineering course.  The teachers don't like to use loops, ifs, else, for, whiles etc. So sometimes I don't know what is allowed. But I will as if loops are ok

Comment: @HarryStylesheet if you want to WOW them use the reduce version :P

Comment: I think the will like that, the whole course is about making function compositions, functors, monoids and monads.

Comment: @HarryStylesheet nah .. you would need to write imperative code in TS for that, no points for that :P.